# Limit MySQL forked processes

Tags: mysql, mysql5.5

How can you limit the amount of processes that MySQL forks? I noticed at startup there are at least 10 children. This is a development database that isn't in production; so no users are connecting to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to reduce the number of processes/threads, by changing following values:

[max_user_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections)

[max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections)

[max_delayed_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_delayed_threads)

For example in my.cnf:

```
max_connections = 1
max_user_connections = 1
max_delayed_threads = 1
```

But this does not guarantee that there will be less processes/threads, as not all processes/threads are connection related.

Comment: Unfotunately, there is no simple solution to limit the processes.

Answer (score 0):

use max_user_connections to limit the number of connections that a single mysql user can have at one time

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections

you'd need to try a few different settings / combinations of max_connections and max_user_connections to get the best performance without running out of connections.

also, its not a 1:1 ratio between connections and threads.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/threads.html

Answer (score 0):

What @b13n1u said. If this doesn't help, any program can be limited by standard `ulimit` limits, cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux) as a related example.

To limit `mysqld` processes in Linux, set e.g. "`ulimit -u 5`" before starting `mysqld`, maybe add this to the mysql init script.